# Running npm start : dyld[1101]: Library not loaded: Mac OS

Tags: node.js, macos

On packages update and brew cleanup, my node projects stopped running. I Get the error below on running npm start.

```
dyld[1101]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.6.0/bin/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      npm -V
```

How do I sort it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it. The issue seems to be that when the update happened, it removed node from the system.

Resolution: `brew install node`